# Proof $\varphi:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p_1 ^{a_1}\mathbb{Z} \times...\times\mathbb{Z}/p_3 ^{a_3} \mathbb{Z}$ is surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

I want to prove a homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p_1 ^{a_1}\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/p_2 ^{a_2}\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p_3 ^{a_3} \mathbb{Z}$ is surjective, where $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are distinct prime integers, $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are positive integers.

Define $\varphi (x) =(\bar{x}, \bar{x}, \bar{x})$. I know if there is only $p_1,p_2$, we can prove it by Chinese remainder theorem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can still use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $p_1^{a_1},...p_n^{a_n}$ are coprime, so there exists (unique) $x$ such that $x \equiv b_i$ mod $p_i^{a_i}$, for each $b_i \in \mathbb{Z}/p_i^{a_i}\mathbb{Z}$ any $i$ therefore we always have pre-image. Is this correct?

Comment: Its correct but $x$ is only unique modulo the product of $p_i^{a_i}$.

Comment: In general, if $f:R\to R/I_1 \times \cdot \cdot \cdot R/I_n$ is a ring gomomorphism, then $f$ is surjective if and only if the family $(I_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ is pairwise comaximal.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*
The index of $\ker \varphi$ is equal to the size of the codomain.